# share property among dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

Is it possible to share a property between two dependencies?

This is my layout:

```
PARENT (can't change this)
    - proj A (Can't change this either - has a lot of properties)
        - proj B (Need to specify which version of proj A I will use when compiling this)
```

so I changed it to become:

```
PARENT
    - proj A
    - proj B (no longer a son of proj A and now importing proj A as dependency of scope import type pom)
```

The problem is that I have now lost proj A's properties that I need to access in project B!

Can you see a solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to share properties is using inheritance. Since you can't change `PARENT`, the solution is to create an intermediate parent pom for `proj A` and `proj B`.

The resulting layout would be :

```
PARENT
    COMMON_PROPERTIES_PARENT (with properties used by proj A and proj B)
        - proj A
        - proj B (no longer a son of proj A and now importing proj A as dependency of scope import type pom)
```

Comment: I will not be able to reuse the properties in proj A but I guess I can atleast duplicate them. =)